# What resources should be used to create a Subscription to a particular calendar via the Graph v1.0 API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm working on integrating my existing app with the Graph API. Using the Outlook APIs we were able to create "calendar webhooks" and "calendar event webhooks". According to the docs, calendar events webhooks are `Subscription`s with the `resource_type` `me/events`. Is there any modifier to scope down to a Calendar ID? Additionally, is there any way to subscribe to calendars being added or removed?

I've tried `me/events/{id}`, `me/events`, `/me/calendars/{id}/events`, and `/me/calendars/{id}` to no avail

```py
API_BASE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'

def api_url(fmt, *args, **kwargs):
    """Helper for generating API URLs"""
    return API_BASE + fmt.format(*args, **kwargs)


def _create_push_subscription(self, callback_url):
    """Create a push subscription"""

    expiration = now() + timedelta(days=2)

    # Initialize some parameters
    data = {
        'resource': '/me/calendars/{}/events'.format(calendar_id),
        'subscriptionExpirationDateTime': str(expiration.isoformat()).replace('+00:00', 'Z'),
        'changeType': 'created,deleted,updated',
        'notificationURL': callback_url,
    }

    # Create the subscription
    resp = self.session.post(api_url('/subscriptions'), json=data)

    # Return the channel ID and expiration date
    return parse_datetime(resp['subscriptionExpirationDateTime'])
```

The only responses I've gotten are `503 (Gateway timeouts)` and

```
400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#resources-examples), you can only subscribe to `/me/events`:

> The following are valid values for the resource property of the subscription:
>
> - Mail: `me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages` `me/messages`
> - Contacts: `me/contacts`
> - **Calendars: `me/events`**
> - Users: `users`
> - Groups: `groups`
> - Conversations: `groups('*{id}*')/conversations`
> - Drives: `me/drive/root`
> - Security alert: `security/alerts?$filter=status eq ‘New’`